# to add a custom rule in validator to check <ul> has element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I want to check whether my `<ul>` has children or not while submitting a form.
Here is my html below:

```
 <form>
        /*other input elements*/
        <div class="attributes-added">
        <ul name = "attributesAddedList">
        // by default no element is present
        </ul>
        <input type = "submit" value = "save"> </div> 
   </form>
```

As you can see the provided ul has children (`<li>`) by default. User need to add them dynamically which is not an issue.
But what i need is when i submit the form it should check whether the `ul` has children or not in the `jQuery validator` using custom function.

I have tried the validator like below but no fruitful outcome yet.

```
$("#templateForm").validate({
    rules: {
        attributesAddedList:{
                addedCategory: $(".attributes-added ul").has("li").length
           }
    },
    message: {
         attributesAddedList:{
                addedCategory: "the message"
           }
    }
});
```

Now for custom function

```
$.validator.addMethod("addedCategory", function(value, element, len) {
    if(len < 0){
        return false;
    }
}, "choose a category");
```

Any help?

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin can only validate `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements contained within a `form`.  It was designed to let the user know they've improperly filled out a form.  It cannot test any other kind of element, nor was it intended to test your DOM for a particular structure.  I recommend re-evaluating why you are doing this and perhaps write a custom jQuery solution instead.  Otherwise, copying a value into a hidden input element will allow you to run validation on that instead.

Answer (score 2):

I used a hidden input to add a rule,
but i would suggest using the submit handler instead, but this way you can use the .valid() method, instead of having to wait for a submission of the form,
hope this helps

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("hasAttributes", function(value, element) {
  console.log('bla');
  return $("ul > li").length > 0
})

console.log($("#templateForm").validate({
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    attr: {hasAttributes: true}
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert(this.valid()); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        },
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { alert('oops, no attributes'); }
}));


$("#templateForm").valid()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="templateForm">
        /*other input elements*/
        <div class="attributes-added">
          <input type="hidden" id="attr" name="attr">
        <ul name = "attributesAddedList">
        // by default no element is present
        </ul>
        <input type = "submit" value = "save"> </div> 
   </form>
```